# How to use TurboRepo to rebuild apps that rely on a changed package (local)

Tags: javascript, monorepo, turborepo

I'm currently setting up [TurboRepo](https://turborepo.org/) alongside yarn workspaces and I'm having trouble getting it to rebuild our main app whenever one of the local packages it relies on changes.

Here is an example of my file structure:

```
├── apps                   
│   └── web
├── packages              
│   ├── assets                 
│   ├── config                 
│   ├── design-system          
│   ├── hooks                  
│   └── utils
```

Here is my turbo.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "baseBranch": "origin/main",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": [".sst/**", ".build/**", ".expo/**"]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to only rebuild packages/apps whenever they have changed in git, so I am using the `--filter=[origin/main]`. I made a small change to the `hooks` package and expected it to need to rebuild `hooks`, hooks dependencies, and `web` (because `web` has hooks as a dependency in its package.json). However, it only tries to rebuild `hooks` and hooks dependencies.

To test, I am experimenting with the following command:
`yarn turbo run build --filter=[origin/main] --dry-run`

This prints out the following output:

```
@hlp/config#build
  Task          = build
  Package       = @hlp/config
  Hash          = 118d81f38208c721
  Directory     = packages\config
  Command       = <NONEXISTENT>
  Outputs       = .sst/**, .build/**, .expo/**
  Log File      = packages\config\.turbo\turbo-build.log
  Dependencies  =
  Dependendents = @hlp/hooks#build, @hlp/utils#build
@hlp/utils#build
  Task          = build
  Package       = @hlp/utils
  Hash          = 0c879c46fe4a9144
  Directory     = packages\utils
  Command       = <NONEXISTENT>
  Outputs       = .sst/**, .build/**, .expo/**
  Log File      = packages\utils\.turbo\turbo-build.log
  Dependencies  = @hlp/config#build
  Dependendents = @hlp/hooks#build
@hlp/hooks#build
  Task          = build
  Package       = @hlp/hooks
  Hash          = 4be940dedd5cc599
  Directory     = packages\hooks
  Command       = <NONEXISTENT>
  Outputs       = .sst/**, .build/**, .expo/**
  Log File      = packages\hooks\.turbo\turbo-build.log
  Dependencies  = @hlp/utils#build, @hlp/config#build
  Dependendents =
```

As you can see, it does not try to rebuild `web`. Is there any way to trigger `web` to rebuild since its dependency changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in docs (https://turborepo.org/docs/core-concepts/filtering), you should be able to **include dependents of matched packages** by using `...` prefix before query (e.g. `--filter=...[origin/main]`)

```bash
# Build everything that depends on changes in branch 'my-feature'
turbo run build --filter=...[origin/my-feature]
```

Comment: I believe this did the trick. Thanks!